# Is this problem a Permutation or a Combination? (I just want to be sure)

Tags: probability

Suppose you are asked to list, in order of
preference, the three best movies you have
seen this year. If you saw 20 movies during
the year, in how many ways can the three
best be chosen and ranked?

Answer (score 4):

Permutations count arrangements with *no repetition* where *order matters*.

Combinations count arrangements with *no repetition* where *order does **not** matter*.

Your problem asks, "Suppose you were asked to list, *in **order** of preference*, the three best movies you have seen this year..."

Does order matter?

Answer (score 0):

It is a permutation problem. The answer is 20 * 19 * 18 = 6840.

Answer (score 0):

Just "chosen", all three at once, means you count combinations.

"Chosen and ranked", i.e. chosen in order, first, then second, then third, means you count permutations.